# ASP.NET MVC 2: Where is ModelState.AddUnhandledError Defined?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I've seen `ModelState.AddUnhandledError` in a few code samples, but it doesn't seem to be part of the `ModelStateDictionary` class.  Presumably it's an extension method?

Is this a standard part of MVC? Anyone know where this is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not part of the standard MVC. Presumably it's a custom defined extension method.